# install faststart cloud in a box

Tags: database, centos, ontology, eucalyptus

I want to install FastStart on my laptop (cloud-in-a-box), 
My current operating system is Windows 7
So, I burned the FastSTART on a DVD 
It is recommended to install linux before or the DVD wil install both the system Centos and FastSTART?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The DVD will install both CentOS and Eucalyptus. The installation is quite straightforward, but understand that installing a new Operating System, such as CentOS means that you will lose your Windows 7 installation. Prior to installing, please make backups of everything you may need. Have a look [here](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#faststart-guide/install_cloud_in_a_box.html) for the instructions to install Eucalyptus from the faststart iso.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at the YouTube video that is produced by Eucalyptus.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsIRAKNQMGc

Basically it will wipe out the existing operating system and data on your machine and put CentOS on it.  Don't do this on your main machine.  Do it on another machine.